# I cant make my div change on hover at all

Tags: html, css

I am simply trying to change a div color from light blue to black. unfortunately I can not make it change color, or anything. I have tried various codes but none of them seem to work. Here is my code.

```
**HTML**




    <a href="#">
    <div id="entertainment">
    <h1 style="font-size:25px;"> Entertainment </h1>
    </div>
    </a>
```

and here is my    **CSS**

```
    #entertainment{
     background-color:#6db1e1;
     width:160px;
     height:70px;
     margin-top:5px;
     margin-left:334px;
     position:absolute;
    }

     a,entertainment{

    color:black;
    text-decoration: none;
     }
```

a.entertainment:hover{

```
margin-radius:20px;
background-color:green;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `a.entertainment:hover` does not work with your html setup. What you are saying with that line is "I want to target an a tag that has a class and is hovered"

In order to make the code work with your html structure, you have to to remove the a tag from the css selector:

```
#entertainment:hover {
  /* hover style here */
}
```

```css
#entertainment{
     background-color:#6db1e1;
     width:160px;
     height:70px;
     margin-top:5px;
     margin-left:334px;
     position:absolute;
}

a,entertainment{

    color:black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
     
#entertainment:hover{

    border-radius:20px;
    background-color:green;

}
```

```html
    <a href="#">
    <div id="entertainment">
    <h1 style="font-size:25px;"> Entertainment </h1>
    </div>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using an ID for entertainment you need to give it a # inside the css like you did with it's initial styles.

```
#entertainment:hover { margin-radius: 20px; background-color: green; }
```

Comment: That makes sense now. Thank you Dave!